# Does anybody can help how to avoid edited data automatic commit in LinqPad Edit Mode?

Tags: linqpad

In the latest version V.4.42.14, user can directly edit data in the grids mode, which is awesome. Every time I edit one row data and move my cursor to next, the edited data automatic commit to database. The automatic commit is very dangerous without I click a save button. Sometimes I edit a data just for demonstration purpose, actually I don't want it commit when I move my cursor to next line. Does anybody can help how to avoid edited data automatic commit in LinqPad Edit Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQPad behaves this way to be consistent with SSMS, and to avoid the possiblity of losing large number of edits should you close the query or hit F5 (or close LINQPad) without saving.

It wouldn't be hard to offer the option of table-level buffering if there's enough demand. It would require, though, an enhancement to the extensibility model to allow queries to signal to the host that they have unsaved data, so that LINQPad can offer "Abandon Changes" prompt to avoid the scenario described above.

Comment: Thanks Joe, if you could please consider add a table lever RollBack button.